# I can't add white space to a string in WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add space to a string in a WordPress template:

```
<p class="event"><?php the_field( 'date' ) . " " . the_field( 'lieu' ) . " " . the_field( 'nom_de_levenement' ) ?></p>
```

[image]

Comment: what do they return on their own?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to use the fields as strings, but [`the_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) displays the field. You should be using [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) if you need it to return a string instead of displaying it. Once you combine the strings, you can just echo them all at once.

```
<p class="event"><?php echo get_field('date') . " " . get_field('lieu') . " " . get_field('nom_de_levenement') ?></p>
```